# Regex fails when accounting for white space

Tags: python, regex

I'm applying regular expressions to the following string:

```
mystring = '[<tr class="v" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderHalf_ctl01_rot2">
<td><div class="tore_karten"><div style="float:left;padding-right:2px;">Dortmund: </div><a class="link_noicon" href="/news/fussball/bundesliga/vereine/1-bundesliga/2000-01/borussia-dortmund-17/24285/spieler_evanilson.html" style="float:left;">Evanilson</a><div style="float:left;padding-left:2px;">(90., grobes Foulspiel, <a class="link_noicon" href="/news/fussball/bundesliga/vereine/1-bundesliga/2018-19/bayern-muenchen-14/223/spieler_paulo-sergio.html" style="">Paulo Sergio</a>)</div><div class="sep3"></div><div style="float:left;padding-right:2px;">Bayern: </div><a class="link_noicon" href="/news/fussball/bundesliga/vereine/1-bundesliga/2000-01/bayern-muenchen-14/396/spieler_stefan-effenberg.html" style="float:left;">Effenberg</a><div style="float:left;padding-left:2px;">(55., grobes Foulspiel, <a class="link_noicon" href="/news/fussball/bundesliga/vereine/1-bundesliga/2018-19/borussia-dortmund-17/22046/spieler_otto_addo.html" style="">Evanilson</a>)</div><br style="clear:both;"/>
</div>
</td>
</tr>]'
```

Background: This is supposed to capture suspended players from a football website. I'd like to match those players (more specifically, their id's contained in the URL) that were actually sent off, but the string also contains the players who where fouled.

This gives me the list of all four player ids contained in `mystring`:

```
import re
re.findall('href=".+?/(\d+?)/spieler_.+?.html"', mystring)

['24285', '223', '396', '22046']
```

This is too tolerant as players `223` and `22046` were not sent off. The two cases can be distinguished by making use of the closing bracket. However, I am failing to specify the correct `regex`. In my understanding, this should work, but it yields an empty list:

```
re.findall('href=".+?/(\d+?)/spieler_.+?.html"\s>.+?</a><div', mystring)
```

Desired result: `['24285', '396']`. I have the feeling I'm treating the whitespace after `.html` wrongly. How to I need to specify the regex?

Comment: It is not a *string* but structured information - use a `HTML` parser instead, e.g. `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: @Jan is right. Could you show us the web address?

Comment: Infact, I used `BeautifulSoup` to extract `mystring` but went back to `regex` to look within that. I'll consider it next time ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you use regex to find the numbers in your structured information. Anyway, you can use this regex:

```
import re
re.findall('<\/div><a.*?href=\".+?\/(\d+?)\/spieler_.+?.html\"', mystring)
```

Output:

```
['24285', '396']
```